# Nativescript listview Multiple arrays in each item

Tags: android, arrays, listview, nativescript

I am working with Nativescript ListView and have 4 arrays.

```
//name array
        for (var i = 0; i < employeesJson2.length; i++) {
            empNameArray.push(employeesJson2[i].Name)
        }

        // image array
        for (var i = 0; i < employeesJson2.length; i++) {
            empImageArray.push(employeesJson2[i].Image)
        }
        // phone array
        for (var i = 0; i < employeesJson2.length; i++) {
            empPhoneArray.push(employeesJson2[i].Phone)
        }
        // email array
        for (var i = 0; i < employeesJson2.length; i++) {
            empEmailArray.push(employeesJson2[i].Email)
        }
```

I need to be able to utilize these 4 arrays in 1 listview row.

Currently I just have

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">
     <ListView items="{{ empNameArray }}" id="rolePicker" itemTap="listViewRoleTap" style="text-align: center" rowHeight="50">
      <ListView.itemTemplate>
          <Label text="{{ $value }}" textWrap="true" style="padding-top: 10; font-size: 19"  />
      </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
   </StackLayout>
```

If i add another listview item it doesn't display.  Ideally the items would show up in the same row side by side.  Am i missing a step?  Should I be combining the arrays? If so, How?

Answer (score 0):

Each list view template can only have one root element. That said if you want to visualize, let's say two or three labels, then you will need to wrap then in container layout.

e.g.

```
  <ListView.itemTemplate>
      <StackLayout>
          <Label text="first label" />
          <Label text="{{ $value }}" />
          <Label text="third label" />
      </StackLayout>
  </ListView.itemTemplate>
```

Another thing - why iterating over one array to create four additional arrays? If your business logic allows then you can simply use the array with your JSON objects to populate your list view.

What **$value** is providing is an easy way to bind to value that is not a complex object like a string. So if your array items was of the following kind

```
var myArray = ["ab", "cd", "ef"];
```

Then you can use **$value** like in your example to render each of the value of the current item.
e.g.

```
<ListView items="{{ myArray }}">
  <ListView.itemTemplate>
      <Label text="{{ $value }}"  />
  </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

However, as far as I understand in your case the objects are of the following kind:

```
var myArrayItem = { "name": "John", 
                    "image": "some-image-path", 
                    "phone": 123456, 
                    "email": "abv@xyz.com" };
```

So if you want to iterate and visualize your different key-values then you can do it accessing the key in your binding e.g.

```
<ListView items="{{ employeesJson2 }}">
  <ListView.itemTemplate>
      <StackLayout>
          <Label text="{{ name }}"  />
          <Image src="{{ image }}"  />
          <Label text="{{ phone }}"  />
          <Label text="{{ email }}"  />
      </StackLayout>
  </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```